# Get record in range of multiples of 5

Tags: mysql, view

i have a existing new week_table -

start_date     end_date       weekno   
----------------------------------------------
1996-01-01 1996-01-05        1
1996-01-08 1996-01-12        2
1996-01-15 1996-01-19        3
1996-01-22 1996-01-26        4
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''till
1998-12-21 1998-12-26        156

i am trying to extract records with a count of 5 weeks in group. I am looking at results like

start_date     end_date       weekno_start   weekno_end   
----------------------------------------------
1996-01-01 1996-02-02        1        5
1996-02-05 1996-03-08        6       10
1996-03-11 1996-04-12        11     16

i do get the results but the weekno numbers keep running over the maximum week no in the database. for records over weekno 156 i get rows with null value.

How can i avoid the records with null and limit the view to the maximum week no

my current code is-

```
SELECT (t1.weekno * 5) - 4 AS start_id
    ,t3.start_date
    ,t4.end_date
    ,(t1.weekno * 5) AS end_id
FROM weekcon_table t1
LEFT JOIN weekcon_table t2 ON (t2.weekno = t1.weekno * 5)
LEFT JOIN weekcon_table t3 ON (t3.weekno = (t1.weekno * 5) - 4)
LEFT JOIN weekcon_table t4 ON (t4.weekno = (t1.weekno * 5))
```

Comment: I am still trying to figure out what you're trying to accomplish... are you just wanting to page through the rows and show a start date, end date, and week numbers?

Comment: I have data related to the start_date and end_date which would extract through php. the idea is to group the data in different set of weeks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
select   min(weekno) as `start_id`,
         min(start_date) as `start_date`, 
         max(end_date) as `end_date`, 
         min(weekno) as `weekno_start`,
         max(weekno) as `weekno_end`
from weekcon_table 
group by ((weekno - 1) DIV 5)
order by ((weekno - 1) DIV 5) asc
```

Here is the output:

```
start_id    start_date  end_date    weekno_start    weekno_end
1   01/01/1996  26/01/1996  1   5
6   04/03/1996  24/02/1996  6   10
11  01/04/1996  30/03/1996  11  15
16  06/05/1996  27/04/1996  16  20
21  03/06/1996  25/05/1996  21  23
 Record Count: 5; Execution Time: 1ms View Execution Plan  link
```

Comment: Btw, it's not *quite* right.  I am looking to see where the bug in my logic is.

Comment: Was missing the -1 in the group by.  This puts existing rows into groups of 5 and gets the date range and weekno range of each group.

Comment: You can try that query in my sqlfidle. I dont think that would work.

Comment: It should work, although the results look goofy with that sample data (either that or weekno is a total misnomer)

Comment: You should create a sqlFiddle like mine.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for showing that tool to me.  I didn't know it existed.

Comment: @NiteshOswal remember leave upvote and accept answer if that help you

Answer (score 0):

I create two tables and asign a `rank_id`

the first one is for `star_date` ... will be each row `weekno % 5  = 1`

second table is for `end_date`  ... will be each row `weekno % 5  = 0` and also include the last date of all weeks.

Then join by `rank_id`

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2049e/21)** In the demo you can change the `select` fields for `*` if want see what is happening

```
SELECT ini_range.start_date,
       end_range.end_date,
       ini_range.weekno,
       end_range.weekno
FROM 
    (
    SELECT r.* ,
          (SELECT count(distinct r2.weekno)
           FROM 
               (
                 SELECT *
                 FROM t_week 
                 WHERE weekno % 5  = 1
               ) r2
           WHERE r2.weekno <= r.weekno
          ) as rank
    FROM 
       (
         SELECT *
         FROM t_week 
         WHERE weekno % 5  = 1
       ) r
    ) ini_range
JOIN 
    (
    SELECT r.* ,
          (SELECT count(distinct r2.weekno)
           FROM 
               (
                 SELECT *
                 FROM t_week 
                 WHERE weekno % 5  = 0
                    or weekno = (SELECT max(weekno) FROM t_week)
               ) r2
           WHERE r2.weekno <= r.weekno
          ) as rank
    FROM 
       (
         SELECT *
         FROM t_week 
         WHERE weekno % 5  = 0
            or weekno = (SELECT max(weekno) FROM t_week)
       ) r
    ) end_range
  ON ini_range.rank = end_range.rank
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| start_date |   end_date | weekno | weekno |
|------------|------------|--------|--------|
| 01/01/1996 | 03/02/1996 |      1 |      5 |
| 05/02/1996 | 09/03/1996 |      6 |     10 |
| 11/03/1996 | 13/04/1996 |     11 |     15 |
| 15/04/1996 | 18/05/1996 |     16 |     20 |
| 20/05/1996 | 08/06/1996 |     21 |     23 | <- 23 is last week 
                                              and group only have 
                                              3 week instead of 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2049e/31)**

```
SELECT *
FROM t_week w_ini
JOIN t_week w_end
   ON w_ini.weekno = w_end.weekno + 4 
   OR w_ini.weekno + 5 >  w_end.weekno 
WHERE 
    w_ini.weekno % 5 = 1
and w_ini.weekno < w_end.weekno
and( 
   w_end.weekno % 5 = 0 or
   w_end.weekno = (SELECT max(weekno) FROM t_week)
  )
```